# Retrieving multiple attributes using autocomplete - json encoding

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, tag-it

While creating an input field with tags (like Stack Overflow), I came across [tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it). With the help of this and [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), I am able to create similar functionality.

```
$("#to").tagit({
    autocomplete: {
        source: "/searchUser.php"
    },
    filedName: "name"
});
```

In this case, it simply retrieves the names, whereas I want to associate the ID (ID of the users) with the selected names. On reading a little I came across that fact that we can use something like this:

```
// in searchUser.php script

//while loop starts retrieving all names
    $names[]['label'] = $row['Name'];
    $names[]['id'] = $row['ID'];
echo json_encode($names);
```

But the moment the autocomplete finishes, the `ID` data is lost.

My question is that is there anyway I could store the `ID` with the associated name.

**`Might help`: tag-it plugin provides a functionality of setting the `fieldName` which by creating a hidden input tag.**

```
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="Name" name="name">
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the names, where in that code do you need the id for further processing?